# Django how to modify checkbox labels for MultipleChoiceField?

Tags: python, django, django-forms

How do I modify (i.e. add classes or change the id) the labels for the checkboxes in a MultipleChoiceField?

In my form I have this MultipleChoiceField

```
    questions = forms.MultipleChoiceField(
        required=False,
        label='',
        widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple,
        choices=CHOICES,
    )
```

and when I use the form in my template the checkboxes get rendered with individual labels around them like this.

```
<label for="id_questions_0">
    <input type="checkbox" name="questions" value="0">
    "the question"
</label>
```

How do I edit the label so that I can add a class to it and change other attributes of the label?

Comment: you can target attributes around label[for=] tag. Would that help ?

Comment: yes but where would I put that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [Widget.attrs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/widgets/#django.forms.Widget.attrs),
specifically:

```
questions = forms.MultipleChoiceField(
    required=False,
    label='',
    widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple(attrs={'class': 'my-class'}),
    choices=CHOICES,
)
```

This would apply `my-class` to the radio select.
If you still need to add class to the `label` as rendered, you'll need to [customize `forms.RadioSelect`](https://wikis.utexas.edu/display/~bm6432/Django-Modifying+RadioSelect+Widget+to+have+horizontal+buttons).

Comment: That only changes the class for the checkboxes (which is helpful btw, thanks) but how can I change the class of the labels for the checkboxes?

Comment: I believe it's more straightforward to change stylesheet than a customized widget.

Comment: how would I go about doing that in my stylesheet?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, @yuwang, thrilled to see that this also works for ModelMultipleChoiceField (which allows you to display multiple checkboxes), as you can see below.  There's very little documentation on ModelMultipleChoiceFields, so I wanted to share.

```
class ProposedFlagForm(ModelForm):
    id = CharField(widget=HiddenInput())
    crs_sched_proposed_course = CharField(widget=HiddenInput())
    enrollment_flag = ModelMultipleChoiceField(required=False,
                                               label='',
                                               queryset=EnrollmentFlag.objects.all()\
                                                                              .exclude(display='')\
                                                                              .order_by('display'),
                                               widget=CheckboxSelectMultiple)
    class Meta:
        model = CrsSchedProposedFlag
        exclude = ('_updated','_updatedby')
    #end Meta class
#end ProposedFlagForm
```